# SVG / JS Interaction - THE SIMPLE VERSION

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to create an SVG-based menu. I'm completely new to SVG, and have been searching for 1.5 days for a simple example of interaction between JS and SVG. My document structure is:

```
/LOCAL_FOLDER (not on a server yet)
   +index.html
   /CSS
      +global.css
   /JS
      +navigation.js
   /IMAGES
      +navigation.svg
```

I have a simple html body

```
<body>
    <div id="outer-container">
        <div id="navigation-container" onclick="javascript:changeColor();" >
            <object id="navigation" type="image/svg+xml" data="images/test.svg" >Your browser does not support SVG</object>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

My SVG looks like this (for now)

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <circle id="test" cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

This is the general structure I want to use. As you can see, it has JS from the html head (linked) interacting with my SVG #test. For now, I'd deal with having it change opacity on load just so I can start figuring out HOW to interact.

I've tried JQuerySVG, Raphael, straight JS, JS within SVG, etc, and I can't seem to connect. What I'm looking for (and can't seem to find an operational snippet of) is a super basic example that I can then learn from...

Comment: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/an-introduction-to-the-raphael-js-library/

Will get you up and running with about 30 lines of code, which is pretty basic. Unless you're looking to directly use ECMAscripting in svg, but I'm assuming you'd ask a different question for that.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've tried, I rarely had success using data="", however using something like container.load(your.svg), I could then modify to my hearts content.

another issue is to make sure that the svg data was standard.

from there (I used jQuery) `jQuery('#test').attr('style','stroke:#ff0000')` should change the stroke to red.

Comment: Container.load is lovely, but it's still not working as elegantly as you seem to imply. Here is my code:

    function drawNav(svg) {svg.load('images/navigation.svg');}
    $(window).load( function() {
     $('#navigation-container').svg({onLoad: drawNav});
     $('#link-t-r').attr('style','stroke:#ff0000');
     });

You may notice I wrote #link-t-r, that's an element in the actual navigation file, and navigation.svg is the file i'm working from.

Comment: take a look at http://www.kcrenterprisesllc.com/contact/custom/ to see one in action